# docker stops when importing tensorflow

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

I have a problem when building a docker container using tensorflow. Container gets build fine but when it runs the script 'ai_app.py' and reaches the `import tensorflow as tf` line the container immediately stops. It does not show me any error or something, it is like if i were using ctrl + c inside the docker. Using the `--no-cache` flag does not help, I get the same result.

Below there is my Dockerfile, sh script to run it and the results when building the container. I am using ubuntu 16.04

Edit: I am adding the first part of the ai_app.py

Anyone can help me?

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libsndfile1

COPY requirements.txt /opt/app/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /opt/app

# Add the keys and set permissions
RUN mkdir /Speech2
WORKDIR /Speech2


CMD ["python", "ai_app.py", "xxxx", "6020", "/Speech"]
```

```
#! /bin/bash

docker build -t innovation/speech:latest .

docker run -it \
    --rm \
    --net="host"\
    -v /usr/services/Speech2Text_new/:/Speech2 \
    innovation/speech:latest
```

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB
Step 1/11 : FROM python:3.7
 ---> 9337bc3e7477
Step 2/11 : RUN pip install --upgrade pip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 70d763cdf70c
Step 3/11 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a11ceed42113
Step 4/11 : RUN apt-get install -y libsndfile1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8dbb61916cc6
Step 5/11 : COPY requirements.txt /opt/app/requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c5bee1b79c5e
Step 6/11 : WORKDIR /opt/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f6522f756696
Step 7/11 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a6da3d22e92e
Step 8/11 : COPY . /opt/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 89105f62104d
Step 9/11 : RUN mkdir /Speech2
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 77d923bff58d
Step 10/11 : WORKDIR /Speech2
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 89e150986cba
Step 11/11 : CMD ["python", "ai_app.py", "xxxx", "6020", "/Speech"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cee3a818ef34
Successfully built cee3a818ef34
Successfully tagged innovation/speech:latest
```

```
import sys
import logging
import json
import traceback
import numpy as np
import os
import warnings
import IPython.display as ipd
import librosa
#import torchaudio
#import torchaudio.transforms as T
import tensorflow as tf
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, request, Response, render_template
# from scipy.io import wavfile
# from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
#from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
#from keras.utils import np_utils
#from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv1D, Input, MaxPooling1D
#from keras.models import Model
#from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
#from keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from remote_access.fetching import RemoteFiles


class Speech2Text():
    def __init__(self):
        self.classes = None
        self.model = None
        self.labels = None
                 
            ...
```

Comment: you should add to the question the ai_app.py script.

Comment: As shown, your code only defines a class, doesn't actually run anything

Comment: I added only the first part of the code

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the container stops because AVX support is not enabled